# Get pandas row names if value in pandas row is present

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am trying to convert a one hot key dataframe into a 2 d frame

Is there anyways I can iterate over rows and columns and fill the values having a `1` with the column name.

problem dataframe:

```
+------------------+-----+-----+
| sentence         | lor | sor |
+------------------+-----+-----+
| sam lived here   | 0   | 1   |
+------------------+-----+-----+
| drack lived here | 1   | 0   |
+------------------+-----+-----+
```

Solution dataframe:

```
+------------------+------+
| sentence         | tags |
+------------------+------+
| sam lived here   | sor  |
+------------------+------+
| drack lived here | lor  |
+------------------+------+
```

Comment: What if you have multiple columns with 1 for the same sentence?

Comment: Which part are you struggling with?

Comment: In case multiple columns have 1, then ideally concat the names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can segregate the rows having 1 for every column. For these columns, replace the value 1 with the name specified along with renaming the column names

```
lor_df = df.loc[df["lor"].eq(1), "lor"].rename(columns={"lor": "tags"}).replace(1, "lor")
sor_df = df.loc[df["sor"].eq(1), "sor"].rename(columns={"sor": "tags"}).replace(1, "sor")
```

After this, concatenate the individual results using [pandas.concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html), followed by dropping the columns which aren't required.

```
df["tags"] = pd.concat([lor_df, sor_df], sort=False)
df.drop(columns=["lor", "sor"], inplace=True)
```

To ensure unique values we can use [pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html)

```
df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
print(df)
```

Comment: does the answer help your use-case?

Comment: Hey this was helpful, what should I do to get the values from first data frame, when duplicates values occur?

Comment: thanks a lot really appreciate you putting a bit of your time in for this!